# How to properly initiate WebSocket connection with Google Cloud Load Balancer to avoid connection timeout closures?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, google-cloud-platform

Utilizing socket.io, my WebSocket connections proxied through the GCLB are closed at the interval defined in the backend service configuration:

[image: timeout configuration]

Obviously as pictured, the workaround is an impractically long timeout period, but for the sake of correctness, what is the proper way to configure the WebSocket connection through socket.io (or elsewhere if it is not a socket.io's problem) to avoid these closures?

Reason for closure according to GCLB log is `"backend_connection_closed_after_partial_response_sent"`.

As stated in the Cloud Load Balancer documentation it would seem that we need to send a proper Upgrade response in order for the load balancer to keep the connection alive.

> When HTTP(S) Load Balancing recognizes a WebSocket Upgrade request from an HTTP(S) client **and the request is followed by a successful Upgrade response** from the backend instance, the load balancer proxies bidirectional traffic **for the duration of the current connection**. If the backend does not return a successful Upgrade response, the load balancer closes the connection.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#websocket_proxy_support (emphasis mine)

How can this be done?

Comment: For WebSockets over an HTTP(S) load balancer, the Backend Service (response) timeout is a connection lifetime limit (WebSockets connections are killed after the configured response timeout). Hence, the timeout should be set to the maximum amount of time a WebSocket connection will remain open. The appropriate response timeout value is dependent on the application you use. You will need to do some experiments to find an appropriate response timeout to avoid the connection timeout closures (increase its value slightly and retry; for example, if 30 seconds is insufficient, try 40sec,50 sec etc.).

Comment: @dadykhoff I have same problem, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I just increased the timeout in the backend service configuration to an unreasonably large amount and handle the closures.